# Is ShareKit ready for a real world app?

Tags: iphone, sharekit

I just discovered [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/), and it looks great.

I have one doubt, though: since the "Apps Using ShareKit" page on the site is empty and the latest blog entry is dated August 2010, I'm wondering if the project is still alive and it is ready for use in production for a real world application.

Has anyone used it successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, you guys are fast. ;)
Anyway, I sent a mail to the project's author, and here's his response:

> The project is still alive and kicking, I'm hoping to put out another update pretty soon.